# Is there any other way to fire this query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName
FROM testcategory
WHERE CategoryID NOT 
IN (
  SELECT ChildMuzeCategoryID
  FROM testsubcategory
)
```

First table contain 75k
Second table contain 45k records

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: "NOT IN" alternative for selecting rows based on values of *different* rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286155/sql-not-in-alternative-for-selecting-rows-based-on-values-of-different-rows)

Comment: safety tip: index your column which appears in `where/ON` condition

Comment: Sidenote: Read about mysqli and/or PDO. MySQL is going to be obsolate soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use join:

```
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName
FROM testcategory
LEFT JOIN testsubcategory ON testcategory.CategoryID = testsubcategory.ChildMuzeCategoryID
WHERE testsubcategory.ChildMuzeCategoryID IS NULL
```

Comment: Precisely! Query with JOIN executes a lot faster than query with IN.

Comment: it would be more faster if we write `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN `
[Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818837/why-does-straight-join-so-drastically-improve-this-query-and-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: Thanks it is fast to previous one but still slow overall.. Is there is any way top process this script via some other thing...I have heard about Hive SQL..

Answer (score 0):

This query is perfectly fine, there's no way to rewrite it that would actually cause it to perform any better.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is the best way to do and there is no better way, but I have a suggestion:

Since when working with large amount of rows, it would be better if you have some flag like `testsubcategory` and update it to `1 (boolean)` while updating the `testsubcategory` table. And we can easily use this query:

```
SELECT `CategoryID`, `CategoryName` FROM `testcategory` WHERE NOT `testsubcategory` = 1;
```